# How to mock gmail in service.spec file in nestjs and how to test this?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

***This is the service file... and I am not able to write a test case for this. These methods are further called by the endpoints and I have already tested the controller and that is working but not able to test the service. Service method get messages is calling a method from an external library***

```
constructor() {
        const googleAuth={
            client_id: "soemValue",
            client_secret: "value",
            refresh_token: "value",
            grant_type: 'value',
            url:"testurl"
      }
          this.authProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider(googleAuth);
      this.gmail = new GMail(this.authProvider)
    }
    auth(){}
   async getMessages(data)
    {
        return await this.gmail.getMessages(data)
    }
```

**This the spec.ts test file**

```
 let service: GmailService;
  let gmail2 :typeof gmail
  console.log(gmail)
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [GmailService["gmail"]],
      providers: [GmailService,
        {provide:GMail,userFactory:gmailAuth}
      ],
    }).compile();
    gmail2=module.get<GmailService["gmail"]>(GmailService["gmail"])
    service = module.get<GmailService>(GmailService);
  });
  afterEach(()=>{
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
    jest.resetAllMocks()
  })
  it('should be defined',async () => {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('tests getAll Messages',async ()=>{
    const data={
      "userId":"xyz@gmail.com"
    }
    const result = [{"id": "17642342141234b",
      "threadId": "14234234b"}]
    // gmail.getMessages(data).mockResolvedValue('someValue')
    //  expect(gmail.getMessages(data)).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    //  const result= await service.getMessages(data)
    //  expect(gmail.getMessages(data)).toHaveBeenCalled()
    //  expect(result).toEqual('someValue')
    // jest.spyOn(service,"getMessages").mockImplementation(async()=> Promise.resolve(result))
    // const response= await service.getMessages(data)
    // expect(response).toBe('xyz')
    const response = {
      json:(body?: any)=>[{}],
    }

      

      expect(await service.getMessages(response)).toBe(result)
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

We discussed this over on Discord, but I figured I'd provide an answer here so that it is at least searchable. To mock classes that are not injected via Nest's DI system, you need to use the `jest.mock()` method to provide custom mocks for these classes. To do this, generally, the form is as follows:

```js
jest.mock(<library-name>, () => {
  return {
    exportedClass1: jest.fn(),
    exportedClass2: jest.fn(),
  }
});
```

(This is if you are using named exports and not default ones)

From here, you can make these `jest.fn()` methods return mock implementations of the classes. In this case, I was able to provide a mock like so:

```js
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { GMail } from './cloud-access';

const createMessageMock = jest.fn(() => 'mocked!');
jest.mock('./cloud-access', () => {
  return {
    GMail: jest.fn(() => ({
      createMessage: createMessageMock,
    })),
    GoogleAuthProvider: jest.fn(() => {
      key: 'value';
    }),
  };
});

describe('AppService', () => {
  let service: AppService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const modRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [AppService],
    }).compile();
    service = modRef.get(AppService);
  });

  describe('createMessage', () => {
    it('should create a message', async () => {
      expect(await service.createMessage({ hello: 'world' })).toBe('mocked!');
      expect((GMail as jest.Mock).mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
      expect(createMessageMock).toBeCalledWith({ hello: 'world' });
    });
  });
});
```

This test runs without problem and allows for the mocking of classes not injected. Jest's documentation on this [can be found here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks#in-depth-understanding-mock-constructor-functions)